# ResponseEntity doesn't retrieve Integer

Tags: spring, spring-boot, httpresponse

Want to return simple `Integer` in `ResponseEntity`:

```
 @PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('WORKER')")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/countFiles", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Integer> countFiles(HttpServletRequest request){
        Integer count = fileService.countFiles(request);
        if(count == null){
            return new ResponseEntity<Integer>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<Integer>(count, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

When I do it, at front end site I got without filed named 'count':
[image]

**Before you answer:**

1. At front end site everything works fine
2. The bug is at backend site

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? The above code does exactly what it says. It returns an integer value. If you want a field named 'count', then the field needs to be a part of the data that is returned.

Comment: Yes, it "returns" Integer. But when I call that api at frontend site it returns: http://imgur.com/MNGHIBA. But when I create a simple object with one propery (`Integer`) and assign to it my count variable, then at frontend site I see the count variable correctly. I notice that if I want to return simple `Integer` I need to create `ResponseEntity<Integer>` which is inside the second `ResponseEntity`...but it's not what I want and I think it's not pretty correct..

Answer (score 0):

If you want a field named "count", you need to include the field name in an object or map result.

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('WORKER')")
@RequestMapping(value = "/countFiles", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Integer> countFiles(HttpServletRequest request)
{
    Integer count = fileService.countFiles(request);
    if (count == null) {
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
    }
    return ResponseEntity.ok(Collections.singletonMap("count", count));
}
```

FYI, it may be easier to use the static `ResponseEntity.*` methods to create new `ResponseEntity` instances. Also, you don't need `@ResponseBody` if the return value is `ResponseEntity`.